¿Qué significa realmente chamba?
Vivo en España, en Extremadura, y estos últimos meses han habido bastantes memes con la palabra chamba. Todos relacionados con el trabajo pero realmente me gustaría saber qué significado tiene, y sobre todo donde y en qué contexto se emplea. Además me parece una palabra super curiosa porque la propia terminología de la palabra cuando la escuchas de alguien latino parece hacer que cuadre en cualquier frase, por ejemplo el otro día escuché recógeme esa chamba en lugar de recógeme esa cosa
Sé que en cada país puede significar una cosa u otra, cualquier información es bien recibida. Muchas gracias
Un saludo

Hay que buscar en: site:.mx Aqui tienes la respuesta: https://www.mexicodesconocido.com.mx/chamba-origen-y-significado.html

Como ya te puso @Lambie en el comentario (y no entiendo porqué no prefirió responder a la pregunta)
Chamba significa Trabajo (Chambeador = Trabajador).
Mismo concepto de Camello en Colombia (Camellador = Trabajador).
Pero Chamba también es una forma de llamar a una persona llamada Salvador.
Acá hay otra web que responde en varios contextos a tu pregunta.

¿En qué país le dicen Chamba a los Salvadores?

En El Salvador es donde se les conoce así, y donde sea que haya una comunidad de Salvadoreños. Por ejemplo en Florida ya se hace una diferencia entre "Ir a la Chamba" e "Ir con Chamba" incluso algunos "Van a la Chamba con Chamba"
